# How to extract specific substrings in URLs using R?

Tags: r

**How can I modify my code so that I get "test-maps", instead of just "test"?**

I would like to capture all of the characters between 'https://' and '.google.com' for the following pretend two URLs;

https://test-maps.google.com & https://ulla.google.com

So, I would like to just extract 'test-maps' & 'ulla' using the same piece of code. **I have successfully implemented the following R code;**

```
url <- c("https://ulla.google.com", "https://test-maps.google.com") 
pat = "(https://*?)(\\w+)(.*)"
gsub(pat, "\\2", url)
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

```
"ulla" "test"
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
"ulla" "test-maps"
```

Comment: Use the `httr::parse_url()` function to get portions of a URL, from which it will be easier to extract these parts.

Comment: ok will look into it now and get back to you. Thanks Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the package urltools:

`host_extract` to extract the domain and the host. As we only need the host using `host_extract(url)$host` will return only the host values. 
using `scheme` to get the url schema (http or https), paste this together with `://` and you can `sapply` or `lapply` to get what you need.

```
library(urltools)

url <- c("https://ulla.google.com", "https://test-maps.google.com") 

sapply(url, function(x) gsub(paste0(scheme(x), "://"), "", host_extract(x)$host), USE.NAMES = FALSE)

[1] "ulla"      "test-maps"
```

Comment: Excellent. The most efficient and simple piece of code I've found after reviewing all other answers. Thank you. I've applied this to a large data set of over 53,000 urls, and it has worked for all of them!

Comment: A similar strategy using the same package could be `str_extract(url_parse(url)$domain, "^[^.]+(?=\\.)")`, which saves an `sapply()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a few more options:

```
url <- c("https://ulla.google.com", "https://test-maps.google.com") 

gsub("^.*?//(.*)?\\.google.*?$", "\\1", url)
#> [1] "ulla"      "test-maps"

unlist(regmatches(url, gregexpr("^.*?//\\K(\\w|-)+", url, perl=TRUE)))
#> [1] "ulla"      "test-maps"

library(stringr)
str_extract(url, "(?<=//).*?(?=\\.)")
#> [1] "ulla"      "test-maps"

str_extract(url, "(\\w|-)+(?=\\.)")
#> [1] "ulla"      "test-maps"
```

If we look at the benchmarks for all the solutions listed here and by others:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  r1 = gsub("^.*?//(.*)?\\.google.*?$", "\\1", url),
  r2 = unlist(regmatches(url, gregexpr("^.*?//\\K(\\w|-)+", url, perl=TRUE))),
  r3 = str_extract(url, "(?<=//).*?(?=\\.)"),
  r4 = str_extract(url, "(\\w|-)+(?=\\.)"),
  r5 = url %>% str_replace("\\w+\\:\\//", "") %>% str_replace("\\.\\w+\\.\\w+", ""),
  r6 = url %>% gsub("\\..*","",.) %>% gsub("(https://*?)(\\w+)(*)", "\\2", .),
  r7 = sapply(url, function(x) gsub(paste0(scheme(x), "://"), "", host_extract(x)$host), USE.NAMES = FALSE),
  times = 1000
) 
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
#>    r1  25.188  36.2695  42.09713  40.5385  44.6705   121.243  1000
#>    r2  63.554  93.7230 116.28898 101.6285 116.1940  3407.797  1000
#>    r3  20.644  32.5505  41.63846  39.0320  45.1230   183.720  1000
#>    r4  32.574  45.7445  57.49725  53.5265  60.0635   662.852  1000
#>    r5 305.978 356.8885 422.22098 379.7260 428.6380  4387.231  1000
#>    r6 160.318 198.6030 251.32088 216.3115 241.3045  6136.862  1000
#>    r7 553.548 612.4135 745.39361 638.5895 720.6745 25381.766  1000
```

It looks like the fastest are `gsub("^.*?//(.*)?\\.google.*?$", "\\1", url)` and `str_extract(url, "(?<=//).*?(?=\\.)")`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following:

```
url <- c("https://ulla.google.com", "https://test-maps.google.com")
url
[1] "https://ulla.google.com"      "https://test-maps.google.com"
url=gsub("\\..*","",url)  # Extract everything before first dot (.)
url
[1] "https://ulla"      "https://test-maps"
pat = "(https://*?)(\\w+)(*)" # Extract evrything after //
gsub(pat, "\\2", a)
[1] "ulla"      "test-maps"
```

**Updated** (Added the pipeline solution)

```
library(stringr)
url %>%
gsub("\\..*","",.) %>%
gsub("(https://*?)(\\w+)(*)", "\\2", .)
```

Comment: This looks interesting, for code efficiency could you provide a solution in one operation, instead of two please?

Comment: @Greg: I have added pipeline solution for you. Could you please check?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
url <- c("https://ulla.google.com", "https://test-maps.google.com")
# remove front bit
remove_https <- str_replace(url, "\\w+\\:\\//", "")
#remove back bit
just_host <- str_replace(remove_https, "\\.\\w+\\.\\w+", "")
just_host
```

OR PIPED AS

```
just_host <- url %>%
str_replace("\\w+\\:\\//", "") %>%
str_replace("\\.\\w+\\.\\w+", "")
just_host
```